# Embedded Linux and Cross Compiling

Tags: embedded, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I'm just now starting to learn embedded linux system development and I'm wondering how to go about a few things.  Mainly, I have questions about cross compiling.  I know what cross compiling is but I'm wondering how to actually go about the whole process when it comes to writing the makefile and deploying the application to the board (mainly the makefile part though).

I've researched a good amount online and found a ton of different things have to be set whether it's in regards to the toolchain, the processor, etc.  Are there any good resources to learn this topic and master it or could anyone explain the best way to go about it?

EDIT:
I'm not wondering about how to cross compile in general.  I'm wondering about cross compiling already existing applications (e.g. openCV, samba, etc) for a target system from the host system (especially when there is no support regarding the process with the application, which is common).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need a special embedded Linux distribution, that will take care of cross-compilation process. Take a look at for example [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). In folder **package** you'll find package recipe examples.

For your own software build process you can take a look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). [libuci](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/libuci/libuci.mk) recipe shows, how to use CMake based projects in Buildroot.

This answer is based on my own experience, so you're to justify, if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I learned everything about embedding Linux with these guys: http://free-electrons.com/
They not only offer free docs but also courses for successfully running your box with custom Linux distros. In my case, I achieved embedding [uClinux](http://www.uclinux.org/) in an board with MMU-less 32 bit CPU with 32 MB RAM. The Linux image just occupied 1MB.

Comment: By the way Free Electrons are co-maintainer of **Buildroot**.